# Spring WebFlow2. Should I use Ajax or a transition?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-webflow

Spring WebFlow2 Question. Should I use Ajax or a transition?

I have a screen that my user has to fill out some data.

The user sees a number of radio buttons and and based on the radio button picked he has to pick a store from a dropdown list.  The values in the dropdown list change based on the radio button picked.

Should I do a ajax call to the server everytime the user picks a radio button to reload the values in the dropdown?

Should I use Spring WebFlow2 transition to reload the dropdown back?

or do you know any other better way.. I would like to hear some options.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the items in the dropdown are not static? If so you should just load them up to begin with and use javascript to show and hide the appropriate dropdown onclick of the radio button.

You could do an Ajax call to a Spring Webflow transition which has a renderFragment so that the page only has to replace the dropdown div. I use renderFragments to load tiles, but you are not tied to tiles, I believe you can use other frameworks that do templating.

Something like this:

```
<transition on="radioClick">
  <evaluate expression="formAction.bind" />
  <evaluate expression="formAction.getItems" />
  <render fragments="dropdownCombo" />
</transition>
```

Here's that javascript you asked for:

```
function showstuff(boxid){
   document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="visible";
}

function hidestuff(boxid){
   document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how to do the javascript for the radioclick.. this looks good

Comment: You mean the simple javascript to hide one div and make the other appear? You have to find the element, normally by its ID, and then set its visibility. I'll put an example in the answer where I can use code tags. But this is basic stuff - you need to go do a tutorial. There's lots of things to bear in mind.

Comment: It depends on how you write your Ajax. Just looking at an old app I did with Spring and Ajax & SWF, in the onclick (or actually it might be the onchange) event for the radiobutton, you want to fire off a Spring.remoting.submitForm() call, with all the right params, one of which is the ID of the div that it will redraw using the fragment of html which is returned.